# mongoosejs return a model.find with an altered object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I have an issue with querying my mongoose model and passing an altered object to the next promise chain.

The query does get passed to the next `.then` but without my newly assigned spaceTempName.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

```
  // promise - search for workspace ...
  var promise = Space.findOne( spaceId ).exec();

  promise.then( function ( space ) {

     return Stack.findOne( { _id: req.params.id }, function( err , stack ) {
          stack.spaceTempName = space.name;
          stack.name = 'test';

          console.log( stack );
          return stack;
      });
  })
  .then( function ( stack ) {

      console.log( stack );
  })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Comment: i really don't see how this is a duplicate question.

Comment: OK, it's not 100% clear without explanation. In short, returning a value from a nodeback has no effect. Returning a value from a `.then()` callback causes that value to the next `.then()` in the promise chain. So, in order to make the chain behave the way you want, `Stack.findOne()` needs to be "promisified" in the way described in case 3 of the reference.

Comment: At least, that's the generalised way to approach the issue. The answer by Vadi suggests that omitting the nodeback causes `Stack.findOne()` to return a promise. If that is indeed so, then `Stack.findOne()` is already effectively promisified for you. Just omit the nodeback to get the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a callback here `return Stack.findOne( { _id: req.params.id }, function`, and return `stack` without changes for next `then`. You can get `stack` with changes only inside that callback, or by adding `then` after `Stack.findOne`:

```
// promise - search for workspace ...
var promise = Space.findOne( spaceId ).exec();

promise.then( function (space) {

  return Stack.findOne( { _id: req.params.id })
    .then(function (stack) {
      stack.spaceTempName = space.name;
      stack.name = 'test';

      console.log(stack);
      return stack;
    })
    .catch(function (err) { console.log(err) });
})
.then( function (stack) {

  console.log(stack);
})
.catch(function(err) { console.log(err) });
```

Or better for readability, you can put it into `async` function and use `await`:

```
const updateSpaceName = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // promise - search for workspace ...
    promise = Space.findOne( spaceId ).exec();

    const space = await promise();

    const stack = await Stack.findOne( { _id: req.params.id } );

    stack.spaceTempName = space.name;
    stack.name = 'test';
    console.log( stack );

    // here you can pass stack to another promise
    // and it will have changed name
    await nextTestPromise(stack);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: `stack` will only propagate to the second outer `.then()` if it is returned from the nested `.then()`.